# How can I return specific elements of a list from a for loop on the same line? (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

```
ALL_IRELAND_WINNERS = [(1887, "Munster", "Tipperary"), (1889, "Leinster", "Dublin"), (1890, "Munster", "Cork"),
    (1891, "Munster", "Kerry"), (1892, "Munster", "Cork"), (1893, "Munster", "Cork"),
    (1894, "Munster", "Cork"), (1895, "Munster", "Tipperary"), (1896, "Munster", "Tipperary"),
    (1897, "Munster", "Limerick"), (1898, "Munster", "Tipperary"), (1899, "Munster", "Tipperary"),
    (1900, "Munster", "Tipperary"), (1901, "Britain", "London"), (1902, "Munster", "Cork"),
    (1903, "Munster", "Cork"), (1904, "Leinster", "Kilkenny"), (1905, "Leinster", "Kilkenny0] 

query_team = input("Enter a county: ")
def winning_county(query_team):
    for (years, province, county) in ALL_IRELAND_WINNERS:
        if (query_team == county):
            return(years)
```

The "County" input by the user will search through this list and will only return 1 of the years, I need it to return all of the years they have won and put them in a list together... Any help?

Comment: `return` immediately returns from function.

Comment: you could use a lambda function: `winning_county=lambda query_team:[year for year, province, county in LL_IRELAND_WINNERS if query_team==county]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Instead of returning on the first correct answer, try keeping a list of the years that work and return the full list instead. So something like:

```py
query_team = input("Enter a county: ")
def winning_county(query_team):
    winning_years = []
    for (year, province, county) in ALL_IRELAND_WINNERS:
        if (query_team == county):
            winning_years.append(year)
    return winning_years
```

Comment: Typically, when you think you want to do this, it's better to avoid the `list`, and just `yield` each time you'd `append`. Replace `winning_years.append(year)` with `yield year` and remove all other lines referencing `winning_years`. If the caller wants to use the result only once, they iterate it directly; if they need it as a `list`, they just wrap the call with `list()` and consume the generator.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your year always comes as a first element. If not you can use regular expression package to search the year as well. I just simply do the following to get the desire result.

```
def get_winning_year():
    query_team = input("Enter a county: ")
    years = []
    for i in ALL_IRELAND_WINNERS:
        if str(query_team) in i:
            new_list = [j for j in i]
            years.append(new_list[0])
    return years
```

This will give me

get_winning_year()

Enter a county: Tipperary

Output: [1887, 1895, 1896, 1898, 1899, 1900]

Answer (score 0):

```
query_team = input("Enter a county: ")
def winning_county(query_team):
    return [line[0] for line in ALL_IRELAND_WINNERS if query_team in line]
```